# Mouse buttons and keyboard not working in live USB homescreen

Tags: live-usb, usb-installation

I just got a pretty [nice old PC](https://uk.hardware.info/product/55902/acer-aspire-m5201/specifications) from my in-laws that still has Vista on it. I thought I would try Bunsenlabs linux on it and prepared a bootable USB. I selected the menu item from the bootscreen (with the ps2 keyboard), and everything went fine until I came to the live distro homescreen. I was able to move the USB mouse pointer around on the screen, but the buttons didn't work. Neither did the keyboard show any sign of life, but both peripherals were working in Vista.

Thinking it was the distro, I tried Lubuntu on a different USB drive. The exact same thing happened. I also tried another USB mouse on different ports, but it didn't make any difference. I also checked the bios to make sure all peripherals were enabled.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour before? Thanks.

**Update:** I had an idea to try and older distro, so I tried Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked fine. So it appears only the Lubuntu 18.10 and Bunsenlabs (probably also based on 18.10) is an issue.

Comment: Have you tried the boot drive on a different computer? What make/model is the old computer and it's spec's?

Comment: Yes, the USB distro boots fine on other computers. The specs are linked in the question, but in case the link is down. it's an Acer Aspire M5201.